# Multicolumn list environment

Tags: lists, multicolumn

I want to generate an environment that allows to establish the number of columns.

I tried the following environment but I do not know if the `\AtBeginEnvironment` commands are compatible with `\newenvironment`

```
...

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{ncomunas}[1][2]{%
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\begin{multicols}{#1}}%
}
{%
\AtEndEnvironment{itemize}{\end{multicols}}%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I understand well,  you're probably after the functionalities of the  `tasks` package.

Comment: Have a look at the paralist package, which offers some extra lists (less space, in-line, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `multicols` around `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{ncomunas}[1][2]
 {\begin{multicols}{#1}\begin{itemize}}
 {\end{itemize}\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{ncomunas}[3]
\item abc
\item def
\item ghi
\item jkl
\item mno
\end{ncomunas}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should also consider the `tasks` package.